# How to use Shared Preference in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Im trying to save data into shared preferences in flutter but whenever i call this function i get an message in command line as

**Closure(): => Null**

```
Future saveName(String name)async{
  SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();   
  prefs.setString("name ", name);
}
```

This Function is stored in anouther file and i am calling this on iconbutton onpressed as

```
new IconButton(icon: new Icon( Icons.arrow_right),onPressed: ()=>print((){saveNamePreference(name.text);}),)
```

and

```
void saveNamePrederence(String name){
  saveName(name);
  print("Name Saved Successfully");
}
```

Somebody point me in the right direction

Comment: You don't need to have saveName in a Future if you are just setting something with async. Did you check if you can retrieve the `"name"` after setting the error message? Also check whether name is null.

Comment: i get only one message onpressed i.e. Closure(): => Null no other message is displayed not even the print statement in the saveNamePreference(String name ) is displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The async is not called right. First call `saveNamePreference` with an async:

```
new IconButton(
    icon: new Icon( Icons.arrow_right),
    onPressed: () async {
        var _temp = await saveNamePreference(name.text);
        print(_temp);
    }
)
```

then return the state properly:

```
bool saveNamePreference(String name) async {
    try {
        SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();   
        prefs.setString("name ", name);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now im getting Closure(): => Future<Null>